# Padding 0 for Accodion Answers not working

Tags: html, css

I've set the padding of 'panel' as 0. And yet I see this padding/white space (marked with red blocks in the image below). Where does this padding/white space come from?

[image]

Here's the code:

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `p` element inside `.panel` has default `margin` set.

You need to set margins to `0`:

```css
.panel p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```